# Rigidbody not acting as expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

For the past few days I have been working on some custom car physics as a coding exercise.

What my ultimate goal is to have some semi-realistic car physics something in between the quality of the older GTA games and the recent GTA 5.

Now what I got so far is a quite intricate process which eventually gives me a float which is the exact speed I want the car to go until the next frame, so far I have used the following code to do that;

```
this.transform.Translate (0, 0, speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

However because I want to use the Unity build in physics for collision detection I realised this wouldn't work because `transform.Translate` (as far as I know) literally places the object at that position, thus the object could (if going fast enough) suddenly be halfway stuck through a wall or just completely ignore the collision and appear on the other side of the wall. Now instead I decided to do this:

```
rb.velocity = transform.forward * speed;
```

To quickly note, I am doing both of these in my FixedUpdate and I am currently only using the second example (or at least trying to use it and am miserably failing at it). Due to it being in the fixed update I should be able to at least test it to a certain extend without `Time.deltaTime` usage, which is why you aren't seeing that in the second example right now.

To continue my story, for some reason when I set the velocity of the rigidbody instead of using `transform.Translate` my collision acts really strangely. The car becomes all floaty and nudges forward (stands on its nose) when I hit the wall, I have no clue what could be causing this seeing as I am using my own gravity (the gravity from the original `Rigidbody` is turned off in favor of my own custom gravity, which does result in a downward rigidbody force) and the drag, and angular drag of the rigidbody have been turned down to 0.

Basically my question is do any of you guys have an idea of what could be causing my rigidbody to be reacting in such a manner, literally the only difference between my normal code and the code that is acting up is that single line change.

I've looked in to using `rigidbody.AddForce()` instead but that just doesn't seem to do anything at all and on top of that the whole reason why I am writing my car script is to determine the velocity the object should be moving at thus making something like `rigidbody.AddForce()` which adds it to the velocity of the car more or less redundant and shouldn't be necesarry.

The only reason why I'm even using a rigidbody in the first place is so I can do two things: 1. Easy collisions. It means I can add simple forces such as gravity to it and not have to worry about it going through the floor. 2. easy rotations when affected by physics such as collisions.

If anyone has any ideas on how to do these two things in a custom script I'd much rather do that because as much as I like unity the Unity rigidbody physics are practically worthless in my eyes, however a must have because I can't write my own custom rigidbody and I can't find the source code of the Unity `Rigidbody` either. What I'd rather have is a stripped down version of the rigidbody which allows for easy collisions and easy rotation but without all the stuff like the build in drag or velocity because these are the exact things I want to be able to control myself and have been able to control myself so far when I use `transform.Translate`, but I lose this control when I have to use `rigidbody.velocity`.

Comment: Good thing you're not using .Translate(). This would result in problems quite different than you're expecting. This would circumvent the physics engine entirely and kill (amongst other things) collision detection.

Comment: @steenbergh Well I am trying to stop making use of .Translate(). However as I stated I am still having those problems with the physics acting up. I also found out that .Translate() doesn't actually kill the physics nor the collision detection, it's just that due to that .Translate() doesn't get calculated in to the continuous collision that the object might get stuck halfway through a wall and then ping off in to space because that's the moment where the collisions (fixed timestep) starts thus indeed ruining our collisions -.- but TLDR; Yeah Translate() is kinda good for nothing

Comment: @LAKster Answers should be posted below as an answer instead of edited into the question. You don't seem to be active anymore so I went ahead and submitted it as a community wiki. If you are active and want to submit it as your own answer please @ me in a comment here and I'll try to get the community wiki answer removed so your answer can stand.

Answer (score 2):

according to the documentation you shouldn't use rb.velocity to change the velocity regularly - it could result in unrealistic physics

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html

instead use rb.addforce

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html

hopefully that will solve the issue!

Comment: Well the problem I'd have then would be that addforce dynamicly adds it to the velocity, it doesn't set it. So it'd be rigidbody.velocity += speed every frame instead of it being rigidbody.velocity = speed which is what I'd want. Rigidbody.addForce sadly does something entirely different from what I want from my code

Comment: you could always set speed to 0 so you're not adding force when the car is going the desired speed. Could be worth trying just to see f it solves your other problem

Comment: @AlWyvrn I just tried your idea and right now it doesn't work. The unity physics just don't do anything for no apparent reason. literally all I did was change the line I was using to rb.AddForce (transform.forward * speed); and literally nothing happens. The car just sits there it doesn't even gradually speed up as it should normally do with rigidbody.addForce() At this point it'd probably be less trouble to change to something like Unreal because the standard Unity stuff is getting more in the way than it is helping me right now.

Comment: There's an (official and free) example project that is a car driving around you can download, might be worth having a look at it just to see what you can learn from the code! It's very strange that rb.addforce did nothing, at the very least you should get some sort of change!

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `Translate` with the following:

```
rb.MovePosition(transform.position + transform.forward * (speed * Time.deltaTime));
```

`MovePosition` basically acts as a translate (if you do it like this) except it also counts collisions in to it.

Comment: This answer was originally edited into the question. Asker appears to be inactive so I have added it here as a community wiki

Answer (score -1):

If you want super realistic 3D car physics, should look into ready assets like:
Edy's Vehice Physics https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/403

Also from Unite2015 talks, see example project: "EasySuspension" to build sample 3D car by script:
http://bit.ly/1y8ucNW (from video: https://youtu.be/WGvuP6vV6j4?t=17m8s )

Or is the game top down 2D game? (like early GTA's)

Comment: Eventhough I massively appreciate your reply I was doing this whole thing as a coding excercise, so buying a ready made asset would pretty much ruin the whole purpose of making this thing. I have looked at wheel colliders before and the whole standard 'car asset' you can download nowadays, but I'll be honest the code for that is intertwined and conviluted I could barely get my head around it the first time on top of that I have to be honest, the basic 3D car physics Unity has are really not that good. Still thank you for everything and no my game isn't in 2D it's more (see next comment)

Comment: (continuing on from my previous comment) similar to the more modern GTA's starting with 3, ending with 5 as I said in my first post. Thanks again for the reference points, but for now I'm going to continue figuring out how to do what I was planning to do in the first place.