# Vector2 unity2d movement is not smooth when "space" is still being hold

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, controls

I am making a Unity 2D game but I have an script where the player goes up with vector2 and back down but if it goes down and I still hold space it doesn't go smooth anymore how do I fix that?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class playercontrol : MonoBehaviour {

    void Update () 
    {
        Movment ();
    }

    void Movment()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D))
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector2.right *4f* Time.deltaTime);
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector2(0, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A))
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector2.left *4f* Time.deltaTime);
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector2(0, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Space))
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector2.up *4f* Time.deltaTime);
            transform.Translate(Vector2.up *4f* Time.deltaTime);
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector2(0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your object have a rigidbody attached?  It is possible you are fighting the gravity of the rigidbody.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unity Rigidbody not acting as expected (any ideas for writing a custom rigidbody instead?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33258667/unity-rigidbody-not-acting-as-expected-any-ideas-for-writing-a-custom-rigidbody)

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, this is a known common occurrence with Unity and the best solution is to handle movement with RigidBody...

However, there are other ways around it some are much less elegant, but some are ok.

### Method 1

Using raw inputs.

```
// Get the raw inputs
var x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
var jump = Input.GetAxis("Jump");

var move = new Vector2(x, 0);

// Move horizontally
transform.Translate(move);

// Handle Jump
if (jump > 0) { ... }
```

### Method 2

What you need to do is check for combined inputs and then `return` out of the function.

```
// Handle multiple input first
if(Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D) && Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Space))
{
   ...
   return;
}

if(Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A) && Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Space))
{
   ...
   return;
}

if(Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D)) { ... }
if(Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A)) { ... }
if(Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Space)) { ... }
```

Comment: Why use `transform.Translate` instead of `rigidbody.MovePosition`?

Comment: @Ruzihm We don't even know if the player object has a Rigidbody. You are making an assumption. So within the confines of the question it makes more sense.